# UTF-8 problems in writing a UART-Console on a microcontroller

Tags: c++, utf-8, uart

I am currently writing a uart-console on an ATMega1284p. It supposed to echo the characters back, so that the computer-side-console actually sees what is being typed and that is it for now.

Here is the problem: With ASCII it works perfectly fine, but if I am sending anything beyond ASCII e.g. a '§' my minicom shows "�§" '�' being the invalid or the '§' in case everything works fine. But getting the combination of both throws me off and I currently have no idea where the problem is!

Here is part of my code:

```
    char c;
    while(m_uart->recv(c) > 0) {
        m_lineBuff[m_lineIndex++] = c;
        if(c == '\r') {
            c = '\n';
            m_lineBuff[m_lineIndex++] = c;
            m_sendCount = 2;
        } else {
            m_sendCount = 1;
        }
        this->send();
        if(c == '\n') {
            m_lineBuff[m_lineIndex++] = '\0';
            // invoke some callbacks that handle the line at some point
            m_lineIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

`m_lineBuff` is a self written (and tested) vector of chars. `m_uart` is a self written (and also tested) UART driver for the micro-internal hardware uart. `this->send` sends `m_sendCount` bytes using `m_uart`.

What I tried so far:
I verified that the baud rates of minicom and my micro match (115200). I verified that the frequency is within the 2% range (micro is running at 20MHz). Both minicom and the micro are setup for 8n1.
I verified that minicom works by hooking it up to a little-board I had lying around. On that board any utf-8 digit works just fine.

Does anyone see my mistake or does anyone have a clue at what I haven't considered?

I'll be happy to supply up to all of my code if you guys are interested in it.

**EDIT/Elaboration:**

*Observation 1 (prior to starting this project)*

The PC side program (minicom) can send and recieve characters to resp. from the microcontroller. It does not show the sent characters though.

*Conclusion 1 (prior to starting this project)*

The microcontroller side needs to send the characters back to the PC, so that you have the behaviour of a console.
Thus I immediately send back any character I get.

*Observation 2 (after implementing it)*

When I press '§' (or any other character consisting of more than 1 byte) (using minicom) I see "�§".

*Conclusion 2 (after implementing it)*

Something I can't explain with my knowledge is going on. Maybe a small delay between the two bytes making up the character lead to minicom printing a '�' first because the first byte on it's own is indeed an invalid character, and when the second character comes in minicom realizes that it's acutally '§' but minicom doesn't remove/overwrite the '�'.
If that is the problem, then how do I solve it? Does my microcontroller need to react faster/with less delay in between characters?

**EDIT2:**

I replaced the '?' with the actual character '�' using the power of copy and paste.

*More tests I did*

I tried the character '' and as I expexted (it backs my conclusion 2) and I got "���". '' by the way is a 4 byte character.
Set the baud rate of micro and minicom to 9600: exact same behaviour.
I managed to set minicom into hex mode: it sends regularly but outputs hex... When I send '' I get "f0 9f 98 b9" which (at least according to [this site](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php)) is correct... Is that backing my conclusion 2? And more importantly: how do I get rid of that behaviour. It works with my little linux board instead of my micro.

Comment: Could you please explain better this part? `my minicom shows "?§" '?' being the invalid or the '§' in case everything works fine` It isn't clear how you distinguish valid from invalid runs.. solely based on the output? Does your program just print back everything, or does it add '?' on his own?

Most important: how do you decide when it's time to print data back on serial to your application?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I have edited my question, so that it is hopefully more clear what I mean. In conclusion for you: Yes I distinguish valid from invalid purely from the output because I want to replicate the behaviour of e.g. a linux console via UART. I send back each byte immediately after receiving it.

Comment: Does this behaviour happen even if you buffer all chars on the microcontroller and send them all together?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin yes it does. I tried waiting for n-1 more bytes if the first byte has n most significant '1' bits until it sends them back. Same behaviour but I am not sure how performant my driver is. I am using the micros send-finished-interupt to send the next byte in the buffer (should be quite perfomant) but the buffer might have some overhead due to thread(or rather interupt) safety. Don't know how bad it is though, I wish JTAG hardware would be cheaper! :( I will to try the low level variant though to see if that helps.

Comment: I would like to do some experiments myself, but I only have the atmega 384 (I believe) within the Arduino to try with.. Right now I can't think of an explanation, but I can't help feeling odd about *conclusion 2*.. you said you tried with other serial monitor clients too, right? I wonder if it's possible to take a look to the source code of this minicom

Comment: Wow... I just tried dterm and it works... I guess it IS a bug in minicom.  Welp... I guess I'll go to the bugtracker of minicom then. Btw. its source is available: https://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom/ Thanks so much for your support. I hope you don't feel like you wasted your time now that it's a bug in minicom! Thanks!

Comment: I was reading the sources right now. It's never wasted time when I don't know the answer, it means I'm learning with you. Would you share here the bug report ticket, so I can follow through it too? Sorry I couldn't help you more

Comment: I found a related bug on a tracker: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=477810 I did hit the reply button and sent an email. No idea what is going to happen now. ^^

Answer (score 3):

> **EDIT:** the op discovered on his own that the odd behaviour he discovered is (probably) a bug of **minicom** itself. This post of mine clearly looses its value, unless the community thinks that it should be removed I would leave it here as a witness of possible workarounds when experiencing similar problems.

---

**tl;dr:** your pc application might not be interpreting *UTF-8* correctly as it appears.

---

If we look at the  Extended ASCII Code defined by *ISO 8859-1*,

> **A7**    `10100111`  **§**   `&#167;` => Section sign

and according to this [page](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), the *UTF-8* encoding of § is

> `U+00A7`  **§**   `c2 a7` => SECTION SIGN

So my **educated guess** is that the symbol is still printed correctly because it belongs to the *Extended ASCII Code* with the same value `a7`.

Either your end-application fails to correctly interpret the *UTF-8* *U* (`c2`) symbol, and that's why you get an *?* printed out, or a component in the middle fails to pass the correct value forward. I am inclined to believe your output is an instance of the first case.

---

You claim that **minicom** works, I can not refute this claim, but I would suggest you to try the following things first:

1. try send a symbol that belongs to *UTF-8* but not to the *ISO 8859-1* standard: if it doesn't work, this should rule out your *Conclusion #2* pretty immediately;
2. try reduce the speed to the lowest possible, 9600 baud rate
3. verify that **minicom** is *correctly configured* to interpret *UTF-8* characters checking the documentation;
4. try to use some *other application* to fetch data from your micro-controller and see whether the results are consistent;
5. verify that the unicode symbol *U* you're sending out is correct

---

**NB**: this is kind of an incomplete answer, but I couldn't get everything in the comments. If you're patient enough, please update your question with your findings and comment this answer to notify me. I'll get back here and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I should have stated that earlier but: I use minicom to both recieve *and* send data. Thus whichever encoding minicom uses to send it recieves the exact same bytes back from the micro. And I would like to clap the dev of minicom in the back of his head if minicom does not use the same encoding for input and output by default. ;) But I will test what you wrote.

Comment: @Ch33f it was clear from the context, I am trying being open to all possibilities.

Comment: Could you print the binary value too? I'm curious what the ? stands for

Comment: Take a look at my EDIT2. ;)